# vertical way of looping in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my sample view

```
<style>.listing{float: left}</style>

<div class="listing left-most">
    <div class="col1">dynamically loaded by rails loop</div>
    <div class="col2">dynamically loaded by rails loop</div>
</div>

<div class="listing">
    <div class="col1">dynamically loaded by rails loop</div>
    <div class="col2">dynamically loaded by rails loop</div>
</div>

<div class="listing">
    <div class="col1">dynamically loaded by rails loop</div>
    <div class="col2">dynamically loaded by rails loop</div>
</div>
```

For example: There are totally 3 post and 6 comments. Need to display vertically not horizontally

Is it possible to show this vertically with rails loop? It yes how can i achieve it. I can display it

**Edit 1**

[image]

\

How can i achieve similar design with rails looping. Both title and list will be dynamic from database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, get rid of `float:left`. Why did you include it? The purpose of that rule is to *stop* things from displaying vertically. The default behaviour for block-level elements, which all of your elements are, is to stack vertically. The CSS you've added *explicitly* defeats this default behaviour.

Comment: all listing class is horizontal and col1 and col2 should be vertical